# ARMA models if I have X_t on LHS and X_t-1 on RHS? Or is fixed/random effects ok?

Tags: arima, panel-data, random-effects-model, fixed-effects-model

I have run a model in which I have stock returns at time t on the LHS and volatility, which depends on stock returns in t-1, t-2, ... on the RHS.
Meaning, I dont have the same variables on both sides but rather the present value on the LHS and the past on the RHS. The data is a panel data set.
I used fixed- and random effects models so far, is that valid or is it better to use other models? What are the flaws/biases (if any) occurring in the FE or RE models?

Thanks!

P.S.: This forum is awesome, has helped me a lot! You guys are awesome!

Comment: Fixed and random effect are panel data models, right? But here you have a univariate time series. So how can FE or RE work? Since you also have volatility as an explanatory variable, check out ARCH in mean (ARCH-M) models, see e.g. [here](http://pages.stern.nyu.edu/~churvich/Forecasting/Handouts/ARCH-M.pdf).

Comment: Its a panel data set, I just specified the regression model I used to analyze it.